# Google Places Android API, get Place Photo

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-places-api

Is there a way to get the photos associated with a `Place` through the Google Play Services? For what I have seen, the only way to do this as of August 2015 is through their [Web API](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?parameters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there isn't any way to do that as of August 2015.

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible thanks to version 23 of Google Play services, which came out recently. See an example of this being used natively in Android [here](https://developers.google.com/places/android/photos). [Here's another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32157317/google-places-api-retriving-an-photos-using-getplacephotos) for reference.